# Failed to deserialize access token using Postgres, Spring secuirty oauth2

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have created Rest application  with spring oauth2 using JDBCTokenStroe. Backend is postgres. 
I am able to create access token but while fetching data using this access token application throwing error like 
 "Failed to deserialize access token for 05ba6b42-7624-4281-8e53-5f97376fc3df"
and rest response is :

Invalid access token: 05ba6b42-7624-4281-8e53-    5f97376fc3df
    invalid_token

This application is working fine with mysql db but not with Postgres .
Can any one help me out what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is fixed now. I just updated my postgres jdbc jar file with latest version.  Now its working fine.

Thanks